# What, exactly is a "Pastoral Advice" question?

Tags: discussion

Last night while reviewing questions, I came across one that, ***to me***, screamed "Pastoral Advice question - this person should be speaking to a Pastor - in person - not a group of strangers on the Internet."  I voted to close and left the following comment:

> This question falls under the category of "[Pastoral Advice](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)".
>   While our natural tendency is to want to help you with this type of
>   question, doing so goes against site guidelines. Put simply, This site
>   is not here to guide you in matters of Truth. The purpose is more
>   academic - to explain what the various teachings are. On this
>   particular question, you're asking something that would be much better
>   answered by a Pastor or Priest. I'd recommend seeking one out to ask
>   in person for this type of counseling.

Another user felt that this wasn't really Pastoral Advice, and made a comment to that effect.  In all honesty, the question being asked was answerable, and I agreed with the answer that user made.  After thinking about it and re-reading the question, I can see where this user didn't agree on the "Pastoral Advice" label, but I still disagree... Which leads me to this question.

All this made me realize that with all the effort we put into keeping questions and answers non-subjective, one of our primary reasons for closing a question is somewhat subjective.  We really don't have a documented definition of what "Pastoral Advice" ***is***.

Where do we draw the line?  At what point do we determine that this is something they'd be better off speaking to a Pastor or a Counselor?  I know what types of "red flags" I look for, but my ideas aren't gospel here or anywhere, so I'd like to get a community discussion and hopefully a consensus on this.

Comment: Related: [What exactly is a pastoral advice question?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1666/4188)

Comment: Not just related, it's an exact duplicate.